# sequence diagram: design of complex business logic

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

how can I best show a bunch of checks that are done during item search in an e-commerce system with the result for the dealer to be able to buy or not the item?

They are executed in a couple of loops and in between occur some exceptions, which means a loop maybe will be executed, if some conditions are met and maybe the 2nd loop will be executed as well or not..

It is a bit hard to explain it in written form, I hope that you get the idea.

I would really appreciate some solid opinions/solutions.

Thank you in advance

Ioanna

Comment: Yo might want to start by showing what you have done so far, and what you have doubts about.

Comment: Yo, man ;-) If the logic is complex, your diagrams will be too. Try splitting the logic into manageable chunks.

Comment: I'd consider using UML activity diagram or BPMN diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequence diagram is an usual answer no ?
See [sequences diagrmes](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-examples.html) They contain :

"if" which are opt combined fragment

"if else" which are alt combined fragment

If you are an UML fan :) see section 17.6 of UML document

Comment: The question title already tells SD. I guess the answer should focus on the HOW.

Comment: and you can use ref combined fragment in a part of your diagram to describe complex sequence in a specific sequences diagram to ovoid to publish a diagram will messages.